# Dynamodb method to wait for index status to reach active state

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a method to wait for index state to reach active state while adding new global secondary index to a table? There is a waitForActive() method on table but can't find a similar method for index.

Currently I am using polling to check for index status:

```
while (!table.describe().getGlobalSecondaryIndexes().stream().filter(gsi -> indexName.equals(gsi.getIndexName()))
        .findAny().orElseThrow().getIndexStatus().equals(IndexStatus.ACTIVE.toString()))
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks.